# Does anyway to add class for Ul in yii. I'm using cjuitabs

Tags: php, yii, yii2

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="green ace-icon fa fa-home bigger-120"></i>
            Home
        </a>
    </li>
```

Anyone please help me to add class for ul in juitabs.

Comment: So the question is about Yii or Yii2? Please be more precise with formulation, title and tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs', array(
    'tabs'=>array(
     "<i class='green ace-icon fa fa-home bigger-120'></i> Approved" =>$this->renderPartial('_approved', array('model' => $model),true),
    "<i class='green ace-icon fa fa-home bigger-120'></i> Request"=>$this->renderPartial('_requested', array('model' => $model),true),
     "<i class='green ace-icon fa fa-home bigger-120'></i> Denied"=>$this->renderPartial('_denied',array('model'=>$model),true)     
    ), 
    'headerTemplate' => '<li><a href="{url}" title="{title}">{title}</a></li>',
    'options' => array(
        'class'=>'tabable',
        'collapsible' => true,
        'selected'=>$activetab,
    ),
    'id' => 'yw3',
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'class'=>'tabbable',
        ),
    //'class'=>'tabable',    

));
```

This was my code